# JavaFX - Border + Enable

Tags: java, javafx

1. Как настроить границу компонента?
   Например в Swing:
   `setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.decode("#FF0000"), 1));`
2. Как можно "заблокировать" компонент?
   Например в Swing:
   `setEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. либо [`setBorder(Border value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#setBorder-javafx.scene.layout.Border-), либо можно через [`css`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) ( `-fx-border-width`, `-fx-border-color` и другие)
2. [`setDisable(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setDisable(boolean))